# Transferring Z values into vertices in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, vertices, z-value

I am rookie about vertical issues. I have 2 parallel line feaure classes, one of them has Z values in vertices and I want to transfer these z values to the another line's vertices. It is ok that I can add new vertices to closest place of new line that i want to write/transfer Z values into vertices.

Is there any way to transfer these all Z values into another line vertices?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a picture that illustrates what two of these features and a few of their vertices look like, and the rule you are trying to apply for how they should be matched.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have enhanced my question  but i cant share any kind of sample for now.